# Digital signature in pdf using java api and epass2003 token

Tags: java, security, pdf, itext

I am try to add a digital signature to a pdf using java api, and signature was read by epass2003 token. so,here i done this job(add digital signature to pdf),
and its working fine, but when i open this pdf document in another system it shows 
the "Atleast one signature has problem", bu in my system validate sign correctly please help me.I have attached my code below please find it.

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException, CertificateVerificationException{
    // Create instance of SunPKCS11 provider

    String userFile = "C:/results/test.pdf";
    String userFile_signed = "C:/results/test_signed.pdf";

    String pkcs11Config = "name=eToken\nlibrary=C:\\Windows\\System32\\eps2003csp11.dll";
    java.io.ByteArrayInputStream pkcs11ConfigStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
    sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 providerPKCS11 = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(pkcs11ConfigStream);
    java.security.Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);

    // Get provider KeyStore and login with PIN
    String pin = "12345678";
    java.security.KeyStore keyStore = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", providerPKCS11);
    keyStore.load(null, pin.toCharArray());

    // Enumerate items (certificates and private keys) in the KeyStore
    java.util.Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
    String alias = null;
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        alias = aliases.nextElement();
        System.out.println(alias);
    }

     PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey(alias, "12345678".toCharArray());
        Certificate[] chain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        OcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
        TSAClient tsaClient = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)chain[i];
            String tsaUrl = CertificateUtil.getTSAURL(cert);
            if (tsaUrl != null) {
                tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl);
                break;
            }
        }
        List<CrlClient> crlList = new ArrayList<CrlClient>();
        crlList.add(new CrlClientOnline(chain));
        Test t = new Test();
        t.sign(userFile, userFile_signed, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, providerPKCS11.getName(),
                     CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test", "Signature", crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0);
}
public void sign(String src, String dest,
        Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk,
        String digestAlgorithm, String provider, CryptoStandard subfilter,
        String reason, String location,
        Collection<CrlClient> crlList,
        OcspClient ocspClient,
        TSAClient tsaClient,
        int estimatedSize)
                throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating the reader and the stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setReason(reason);
    appearance.setLocation(location);
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), 1, "sig");
    // Creating the signature
    ExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);
}
}
```

so above is my code please help me.

Comment: Please share a sample file signed with that token for analysis... *when i open this pdf document in another system it shows the "Atleast one signature has problem", bu in my system validate sign correctly* - This sounds like the certificate for which the token signs is not universally trusted (i.e. its issuer is not on the AATL or EUTL) while you while working with the token granted trust to it on your machine.

Comment: hi thanks for reply, and  you can download sample signed file  in below link please find it https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6t6f1VKlju5UTBheVA3S25VY1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Kindly share the complete code base dump. We are also looking for same working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the signature properties one sees:

[image: Signature Properties window]

This dialog states the problem:

> The signer's identity is unknown because it has not been included in your list of trusted certificates and none of its parent certificates are trusted certificates.

Furthermore a look at the signer's certificate shows:

[image: Certificate viewer window]

Thus, your code only embeds the signer certificate itself, not its certificate path (otherwise they would have shown in the certificate viewer window). Unfortunately the issuer certificate (SafeScrypt sub-CA for RCAI Class 2 2014) is not immediately trusted, neither is that certificate's issuer (SafeScrypt CA 2014), but that certificate's issuer (CCA India 2014) in turn is.

Most likely on your computer either the whole certificate chain is known or at least up to a certificate which is explicitly trusted.

To get the same effect on other computers which only know the root certificate, simply add the certificates for "SafeScrypt sub-CA for RCAI Class 2 2014" and "SafeScrypt CA 2014" to your `Certificate[] chain`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir,and in my code while, loop the aliases it will print only one alias name:"VIBIN SRINIVAS K L's SafeScrypt sub-CA for RCAI Class 2 2014 ID", so how can add the another alias to Certificate[] chain.But in my certificate viewer window shows all root certificate i have attached image link please find it -https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6t6f1VKlju5UnR5ajhNdHllQ0U/view?usp=sharing, please help me

Comment: *so how can add the another alias to Certificate[] chain* - You don't add aliases to the certificate chain but certificates. As it looks like your token does not provide those certificates, you can download them from your provider, load them in your code, and then add them to the certificate(s) you get from `keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias)`. Concerning the image: Clicking the link I am informed that I don't have the permissions required to read it.

Comment: sory use this link -https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6t6f1VKlju5UnR5ajhNdHllQ0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: On your computer most likely those additional certificates have been installed in some certificate stores when you installed software that came with the token. Adobe Reader makes use of these additional certificate stores when trying to construct the certificate path. On other person's computers those additional certificates are not present, so Adobe Reader has no chance to build the certificate path. You need to forward those extra certificates to the other computers, and the easiest way is to include them in your signature by adding them to the `Certificate[] chain`.

Comment: Thank you very much for guidance you gave me ,It was very helpful for me and I really appreciated the time you spent for me.Now its working fine with your help.

Comment: but in this i have one small problem, that is when i click the signature only it will check certificate in online otherwise it will have same problem "signature validity unknown", so, how to validate signature when open pdf itself. Thanking you.

Comment: @user2629598 If that issue persists, please share a new signed PDF with the certificates includes to allow reproducing and analyzing that issue.

Comment: please check this link for referance https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6t6f1VKlju5LUkyMXdkS3locDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @user2629598 I simply opened your new PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC and it immediately showed "Signed and all signatures are valid". Do you have the issues using a different version of the Reader?

Comment: Yes, I opened this in Adobe reader in mac system than it show like that.first time only show like that second time onwards working automatically.but in some system it'll work automatically first time itself

Comment: That looks like an issue of Adobe Reader. Probably it is merely a symptom of those installations having to update their trust anchors. There is nothing you as signer can do about that, short of using a different token the issuer of has been trusted for a longer time.